# How to edit data before to storing into database Realm

Tags: java, android, json, realm

I had a problem for a while, I need to  change Data which is coming from JSON before storing it into database. I did some work but I found just the last element, the others are overwritten, How can I  get all the data.

```
public void setImage(String image) {
    ListUrl listUrl=new ListUrl();
    this.image = image;
    if (!image.isEmpty()) {

        try {
          String  paths= listUrl.Download_images(image);
            if (!paths.isEmpty()) {
                 illustration = new Illustration(image, paths, "", "", true);


              illustration.setPath(paths);
              illustration.setLink(image);
               illustration.setDownloaded(true);
              setIllustration(illustration);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

listUrl to get path of image it works correctly so I don't know the probleme where eexactly

```
public class Illustration extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String link;
private String path;
private String fullLink;
private String fullPath;
private int originalHeight;
private int originalWidth;
private boolean downloaded;
```

//getter and setter

Comment: It is unclear how you save your data. What does setIllustration do()? Also if only the last element is saved, it sounds like perhaps all elements have the same primary key, thus overriding each other.

Comment: thank's, but first I save paths and image in illustration, for setIlustration for saving data wich are paths and image in database , you're right I found the same primary key, so I remove @Primary key from class model Illustration and I found that data is duplicated for each run, I hoped that you understand my probleme now, because I don't need to dpulcated data just storage !

Comment: You should take a look at the `Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate()` method.